# jquery overlay background dimming doesn't go away on IE9 after overlay dismissed

Tags: javascript, jquery, overlay

Let me preface this by saying that I'm new to jquery and fairly new to javascript.

I searched around a bit and found a overlay tutorial I was able to follow and at this point I don't even remember where I got it.  I've got the following that works (almost):

```
function showOverlayBox() {
//if box is not set to open then don't do anything
if( isOpen == false ) return;
// set the properties of the overlay box, the left and top positions
$('.overlayBox').css({
    display:'block',
    left:($(window).width() - $('.overlayBox').width()) / 2,
    top:($(window).height() - $('.overlayBox').height()) / 2 -20,
    position:'absolute'
});
// set the window background for the overlay. i.e the body becomes darker
$('.bgCover').css({
    display:'block',
    width: $(window).width(),
    height:$(window).height()
});
}

function doOverlayOpen() {
//set status to open
isOpen = true;
showOverlayBox();
$('.bgCover').css({opacity:0}).animate({opacity:0.5, backgroundColor:'#000'});
// dont follow the link : so return false.
return false;
}

function doOverlayClose() {
//set status to closed
isOpen = false;
$('.overlayBox').css( 'display', 'none' );
// now animate the background to fade out to opacity 0
// and then hide it after the animation is complete.
$('.bgCover').animate({opacity:0}, null, null, $(this).hide(););
}

<style type="text/css">
body { font:76% verdana; }
.bgCover { background:#000; position:absolute; left:0; top:0; display:none; overflow:hidden }
.overlayBox {
border:5px solid #09F;
position:absolute;
display:none;
width:500px;
height:300px;
background:#fff;
overflow: scroll;
}
.overlayContent {
padding:10px;
}
.closeLink {
float:right;
color:red;
}
a:hover { text-decoration:none; }

h2 {
padding:5px;
margin:0;
}
</style>

<div class="bgCover">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="overlayBox">
<div class="overlayContent">
    <a href="#" class="closeLink">Close</a>
</div>
</div>
<a href="#" class="launchLink">Launch Window</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
// if window is resized then reposition the overlay box
$(window).bind('resize',showOverlayBox);
// activate when the link with class launchLink is clicked
$('a.launchLink').click( doOverlayOpen );
// close it when closeLink is clicked
$('a.closeLink').click( doOverlayClose );
</script>
```

This runs fine for me in a standalone page.  However, for some reason when I put this into the page I need it on, when I click the close on the overlay box, bgCover doesn't go away.  This happens in IE9 but not in FF 3.6.10.  If i comment out the line:

```
$('.bgCover').css({opacity:0}).animate({opacity:0.5, backgroundColor:'#000'});
```

in doOverlayOpen, it works as expected except of course that the .bgCover is all black and not transparent (I'm guessing this is because the animation doesn't ever happen).

If I replace the function call in the doOverlayClose animate call (currently just executing $(this).hide();) with a function, I can see that it never gets called. example:

```
function doOverlayClose() {
//set status to closed
isOpen = false;
$('.overlayBox').css( 'display', 'none' );
// now animate the background to fade out to opacity 0
// and then hide it after the animation is complete.
$('.bgCover').animate({opacity:0}, null, null, testFunction);
}

function testFunction() {
    alert("GotHere!");
    $(this).hide();
}
```

The alert never fires.

It appears as though the remove line never happens on IE9 for some reason under some circumstances but I can't figure out why.

Obviously it is a difference in environment between the two pages (where it works and where it doesn't) but I'm not finding anything to tell me what exactly.  Can anyone point me in the right direction of what I should be looking for?

Answer (score 0):

What happends if you do not use the css?

```
doOverlayOpen{
...
    $('.bgCover').animate({opacity:0.5, backgroundColor:'#000'});
}

doOverlayClose
...
    $('.bgCover').animate({opacity:0, backgroundColor:'transparent'});
}
```

Comment: That causes the initial animation to "fade out" instead of "fade in".  but it doesn't solve the problem on the remove either.  Essentially, the problem I am having is that when clicking the close link from the overlay, doOverlayClose executes but $(this).hide(); doesn't execute.  I've also tried replacing that with a separate function and verified this.